# Access several tables with only one query

Tags: python, django

I have the same schema in my django application:

```py
class SomeModel(models.Model):
    value = models.CharField(max_length=30)


class AbstractModel(models.Model):
    someModel = models.ForeignKey(SomeModel)

    class Meta:
            abstract = True


class A(AbstractModel):
    anotherValue = models.CharField(max_length=5)

class B(AbstractModel):
    anotherValue = models.CharField(max_length=5)

class C(AbstractModel):
    anotherValue = models.CharField(max_length=5)

class D(AbstractModel):
    anotherValue = models.CharField(max_length=5)

class E(AbstractModel):
    anotherValue = models.CharField(max_length=5)
```

With this layout, I need the most efficient way to query all objects from models A, B, C, D and E with a given id of SomeModel. I know that I cannot execute a query in an abstract model, so right now, what I do is query each model separately like this:

```py
A.objects.filter(someModel__id=id)
B.objects.filter(someModel__id=id)
C.objects.filter(someModel__id=id)
D.objects.filter(someModel__id=id)
E.objects.filter(someModel__id=id)
```

Obviously this approach is quite slow, because I need to make 5 different queries each time I want to know all those objects. So my question is, is there a way to optimize this kind of query?

UPDATE:

I have tried the union method like this:

```
qs1 = A.objects.filter(**filters) # hits DB
qs2 = B.objects.filter(**filters) # hits DB
qs3 = C.objects.filter(**filters) # hits DB
qs4 = D.objects.filter(**filters) # hits DB
qs5 = E.objects.filter(**filters) # hits DB
qs1.union(qs2, qs3, qs4, qs5) # hits DB
```

That's actually 6 hits to the database!! I woulk like only one!

I have checked this printing the number of queries made:

```
from django.conf import settings
settings.DEBUG = True
from django.db import connection
print(len(connection.queries))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use [union](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#union) method, but what you want to do? If you want to call five objects by one pk and you want to be sure that they have strict relation between each other you may use [OneToOne relationship](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/).

So in the first case you just need to make a query, in the second case you must make new migration and maybe you will need to rebuild your tables.

Comment: But is this faster than my current implementation? Would I need a migration to support it?

Comment: Using one heavy query it always better than use several light because it will have only one call to db instead five

Comment: I edited my answer polymorphic models is not good solution for you

Comment: OneToOne relation is not possible because one SameModel is related to several objects of A (same for the others). I think I will try thew union method and if that's speeds up the process.

Comment: I have just check it and the union method does not make a single query, the consult in the query set is executed right away when you define it. I have added an update to my post.